# Can't pass variable to header (XMLHttpRequest)

Tags: javascript, request

```
uploadImageCallBack(file) {

     var token = ' eyJhbG6Aw5/MwymOfs4B76D5JEr/o0YymuXZufo='
  return new Promise(
    (resolve, reject) => {
      const xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
      xhr.open('POST', 'https://dev.hylaa.net/oa/file/upload');
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization':'Bearer ' + token);
      xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data');
      const data = new FormData();
      data.append('image', file);
      xhr.send(data);
      xhr.addEventListener('load', () => {
        const response = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        resolve(response);
      });
      xhr.addEventListener('error', () => {
        const error = JSON.parse(xhr.responseText);
        reject(error);
      });
    }
  );
}
```

Can't pass variable "token" to header

SyntaxError: Unexpected token, expected ,

where my mistake ? when I use AXIOS I can pass variable to this header

Comment: Because it is suppose to be a string!, what you have is a label.... XMLHttpRequest.setRequestHeader(header, value)

Comment: `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization':'Bearer ' + token);` should be `xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);` i think

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have a [label](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Statements/label), you are not setting the header correctly. Should be [("header", "value")](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/XMLHttpRequest/setRequestHeader)

```
xhr.setRequestHeader('Authorization', 'Bearer ' + token);
xhr.setRequestHeader('Content-type', 'multipart/form-data');
```